# Let $A = \{1- \frac 1n : n \in \mathbb Z ^+\}$ is closed under certain topologies on $\mathbb R$.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Let $A = \{1 - \frac 1n : n \in \mathbb Z ^+\}$ is closed under certain topologies on $\mathbb R$.

I am supposed to figure out if this set is closed under certain topologies.  I know that means I need to show the complement of the set is open.  I am having a lot of difficulty with two things: 1. figuring out what this set actually is 2. figuring out the differences between the different topologies.

I know for it to be false I need to just show one counterexample.  For it to be true I am going to have to show that all three conditions of a topology are met: the set and the complement are in the topology, the union of any collection of sets is in the topology and the finite intersection of sets is in the topology.

I am supposed to look at the three following topologies for this set all in $\mathbb R$

**The usual topology:** is just the three conditions listed above. 
**The half open interval topology**: The collection of $\mathfrak H$ of all subsets of $U$ such that either $U = \emptyset$ or for each $ x \in U$ there is an interval of the form $[a, b) \subseteq U$ is a topology for $\mathbb R$
**The countable complement topology** $ \{ U: \mathbb R - U$ is countable$\} \cup \{ \emptyset, \mathbb R\}$

I would appreciate help in just being able to wrap my brain around the different topologies and what this set might actually look like.

Comment: Do you correctly define "half" open interval topology?

Comment: Under the usual topology it is clearly not closed: the sequence $1- \frac 1 n$ tends to $1$, which does not belong to $A$.

Comment: @Salomo I did not.  I will edit.

Comment: You should check what is meant by "the usual topology." The three conditions you mention are satisfied by any topology, not just the usual one.

Comment: @AlexM. is that another way of saying 1 is a limit point and therefore the set is not closed since the set does not contain the limit point?

Comment: Yes, this is it.

Answer (score 1):

As $A$ is countable (that is there is bijection $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $A$, precisely, $f(n)=1-\frac{1}{n}$), it is obviously a closed set in the countable complement topology.

Comment: Why is A obviously countable? Sorry new learner here!

Comment: @AlyssaWallace Edited with more explanation.